# Modifying sort option on OPENCART Category Page

Tags: php, html, sorting, e-commerce, opencart

does anyone know how to create/modify the sort on category page into something like this website 
http://esqido.com/collections/the-mink-collection.

So I think it's basically sort all the products by its model or categories However, the value of the sort options are also change (Light Volume, Medium Volume, and Maximum Volume). I have been looking for the the answer and havent found one. Really need your help. Thank You in advance

Comment: What's the question, exactly? Do you want to provide a "sort" interface, like the link you provided? Do you want a module? (Have you looked for one?) Are you able to modify your template file(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Post your sorting data by this code and your function response.

```
    <form id="sortForm" action="your function page" method="POST">
        <select name="volume" id="volume">
            <option value="0">All</option>
           <option value="1">Light Volume</option>
           <option value="2">Medium Volume</option>
           <option value="3">Maximum Volume</option>
       </select>
    </form>
    <script type="javascript/text">
    window.jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        window.jQuery('#volume').on('change',function(){
            window.jQuery('#sortForm').submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```